# Wacom One on Ubuntu 20.04. Pen is working but the screen remains black

Tags: screen, tablet, wacom

I have a problem that I can't solve with the previous posts.
I have a dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04. I recently bought the wacom one (screen + pen). When I plug them in, I can use the stylus to draw etc... but the screen stays black and I can't use the tablet as a visual support. When I turn on the tablet, the logo Wacom appears, then I have the message "No signal, go to power saving mode". Even in power saving mode, the pen is still working.

When I enter:

```
xsetwacom --list dev
```

I get this:

```
Wacom One Pen Display 13 Pen stylus id: 12  type: STYLUS    
Wacom One Pen Display 13 Pen eraser id: 25  type: ERASER
```

In the parameters, the stylus is there but not the screen of the Wacom tablet. Maybe it is important to note that the external screen is plugged to the docker Dell WD19 and the HDMI of the tablet is directly plugged into the laptop.

I have installed the latest drivers (0.47). This does not correct the errors. Would you have a solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: does the Wacom One screen detect a signal? If you turn the tablet off and then on you should see the Wacom logo appear on screen for a few seconds. If the device does not detect a signal a message will appear a few seconds after the logo disappears stating that the device is going into power-saving mode. The screen will then blank and the power light will blink. The pen will continue to function normally in power-saving mode, however, which is why I ask. If the display just turns black without a message and the power light remains steady-on then the HDMI connection should be good.

Comment: Thank you @jigpu for your comment. I edited my question accordingly (the screen is entering in power saving mode).